# How do you deal with technologically impaired and ignorant clients?

Tags: client, users, older-users

I got an email today from my parents, that the navigation in their website/shop (Prestashop) is broken and they get an error if they click it. I had a look, and it turns out they manually deleted at least 2 categories.

How would i handle this? I am too busy to help, and the only local "computer guy" doesn't knows anything about Prestashop. When i told them to ask any questions at the official Prestashop forums my parents told me they don't know "the slang" and wouldn't understand anything. What is your advice in such situations?

Comment: oh god how did this get here i am not good with computer

Comment: tl;dr. simple is better, get to the marrow and spare us the fat!

Comment: A shorter question would certainly be easier to parse...

Comment: I have heavily edited your question. SE sites are not forums. Please try to stick to your question. Also, please try and focus on the UX-related questions. Example: how can the application UX be better designed to prevent my parents to disregard warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure this belongs in UX however I would do the following

1. Tell them how long it will take to fix and how much you will charge them to fix it,  if you feel you have to you could offer them a discounted rate
2. Take a backup immediately after you fix it
3. Offer a support contract to them - i.e. you charge them X for a small set of admin functions i.e. backing up, adding users etc. per month for a maximum of y hours, if you go over the y hours then you will charge your normal hourly rate.  Make sure you state the normal working hours you will cover, anything outside those hours would incur a charge regardless of whether they have used up their monthly allocation or not.
4. investigate the use of changing settings to ensure that the users cannot delete anything in the shop, they can disable only.

Comment: +1, but the use of bolding is rather distractive. Your points are short enough that they don't need the extra emphasis.